# Laravel Create Download Link To Storage

Tags: laravel

I have a file in `/storage/excel/exports/abc.xls` and I want to create a download link to it, so I wrote:

```
<a href="{{asset('storage/excel/exports/'.$file)}}" download>{{$file}}</a>
```

But when I click on the link, it cannot find the file. then I looked at href in Inspect Element and the link was *`http://localhost/[my-project]/public/storage/excel/exports/abc.xls`*

And when I cleaned `public/` using Inspect Element and changed href value, the link worked fine and it downloaded the file.

I have different ways to solve this issue but i'm sure none of them is best practice.

Whats the best way to create a link to a file in storage folder in laravel?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @WildBeard Im using Larave 5.5

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Laravel 5.5 you can use the [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#retrieving-files) class. You can then use `Storage::url($file)` and it should get the proper URL for your file.

However, as per the docs:

> Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory.